# Time Complexity of BFS and DFS for bot Matrix and Adjacency List

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1el1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiyZu.png)

above are the pseudocode of BFS and DFS.

Now with my calculation I think time complexity for both the code will be O(n), but I also have another confusion that it might be O(V+E) where V stands for Vertex and E stands for Edges. Can anyone give me a detailed time complexity of both the pseudocode.

So in short, what will be the time complexity of the BFS and DFS on both Matrix and Adjacency List.

Comment: Hi @Andro, can i kindly remind you to mark my solution as answer if it helped you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let us analyze the time complexity of BFS first for adjacency list implementation.
For breadth-first search, that's what we do:
Start from a node and mark it as visited. Then mark all of the neighbors of that node as visited and add them to a queue. Then fetch the next node from the queue and perform the same operation until the queue is empty. If queue is empty but there are still unvisited nodes, call the BFS function again for that node.
When we are at a node, we check each neighbor of that node to fill up the queue. If a neighbor is already visited (visited[int(neighbor) - 1] = 1), we do not add it to the queue. Neighbor of a node is another node connected to it by an edge, therefore checking all neighbors means checking all the edges. This makes our time complexity O(E). Also since we add each node to the queue (and pop it later), it makes the time complexity O(V).
So which one should we take?

Well, we should take the maximum of E and V. That's why we say O(V+E). If one of them is larger than the other, then smaller can be seen as a constant.

For example, if we have a connected graph with N many nodes, we'll have N*(N-1) edges. At each node, we will check all the neighbors, which makes N*(N-1) many checks. Therefore time complexity will be max(N, N*(N-1)) = N*(N-1) = O(N^2)

For example, if we have a sparse graph with N many nodes, and say sqrt(N) many edges, we have to say time complexity of BFS should be O(N).

Same logic can be applied for DFS. You visit each node and check each edge to **dive** into the depths of the graph. And again it makes it O(V+E).

As to your assumption, it is partially correct. However, as I explained above we cannot say that time complexity will always be O(N). (I assume N is the number of vertices, you didn't specify that in your question.)

Notice that these are for the adjacency list implementation.
For adjacency matrix implementation, to check neighbors of a node, we have to check all the columns corresponding to the related row, which makes O(V). And we have to do it for all vertices, therefore it is O(V^2).

So, for matrix implementation, time complexity is not dependent on the number of edges. However in most cases O(V+E) << O(V^2), therefore prefer adjacency list implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it in so detail. The confusion is cleared, do you got any social media??

Comment: Your welcome. I'm glad that it helped. As to your question, I'm not a social media person except Reddit etc., truth be told.

Comment: No like basically I wanted to know any way to contact with you

probably a discord or whatsapp?